# How to list WinRPM-installed packages in Julia?

Tags: windows, julia

In Julia, [WinRPM](https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/WinRPM.jl) is used to install RPM packages from an RPM-md provider.

I understand that WinRPM will install packages to the `deps` folder, but is there some command that can tell me which RPM packages are presently installed in my `julia` installation?

Answer (score 1):

The list of installed packages is stored in the file `installed.list` which is present in the package root directory `~/.julia/v0.5/WinRPM`. The following julia code will read that file into an array of strings. The file mentions all the artifacts provided by the package, so there are duplicates, which can be removed if you want.

```
julia> installed_list = Vector{String}[]
0-element Array{Array{String,1},1}

julia>         for line in eachline(WinRPM.installedlist)
                   ln = split(chomp(line), ' ', limit=2)
                   if length(ln) == 2
                       push!(installed_list, ln)
                   end
               end

julia> installed_list
39-element Array{Array{String,1},1}:
 String["0.18.1.1,18.62,0","mingw64-libintl8"]
 String["0.18.1.1,18.62,0","mingw64(libintl-8.dll)"]
 String["2.48.1,1.22,0","mingw64-glib2-lang-all"]
 String["2.48.1,1.22,0","mingw64-glib2-lang"]
 String["3.0.13,9.40,0","mingw64-libffi6"]
 String["3.0.13,9.40,0","mingw64(libffi-6.dll)"]
 String["2.48.1,1.22,0","mingw64-libglib-2_0-0"]
 String["2.48.1,1.22,0","mingw64(libglib-2.0-0.dll)"]
 String["2.48.1,1.22,0","mingw64-libgobject-2_0-0"]
 String["2.48.1,1.22,0","mingw64(libgobject-2.0-0.dll)"]
 String["2.48.1,1.22,0","mingw64-glib2"]
 String["2.9.0,11.44,0","mingw64-libxml2-2"]
 String["2.9.0,11.44,0","mingw64(libxml2-2.dll)"]
 String["1.6.19,1.20,0","mingw64-libpng16-16"]
 String["1.6.19,1.20,0","mingw64(libpng16-16.dll)"]
 String["6.2.0,3.2,0","mingw64-libgcc"]
 ?
 String["0.30.0,9.40,0","mingw64-libpixman-1-0"]
 String["0.30.0,9.40,0","mingw64(libpixman-1-0.dll)"]
 String["2.4.12,12.40,0","mingw64-freetype"]
 String["2.4.12,12.40,0","mingw64-libfreetype6"]
 String["2.4.12,12.40,0","mingw64(libfreetype-6.dll)"]
 String["1.0.6,3.51,0","mingw64-libharfbuzz"]
 String["1.0.6,3.51,0","mingw64-libharfbuzz0"]
 String["1.0.6,3.51,0","mingw64(libharfbuzz-0.dll)"]
 String["1.14.2,2.43,0","mingw64-cairo"]
 String["1.14.2,2.43,0","mingw64-libcairo2"]
 String["1.14.2,2.43,0","mingw64(libcairo-2.dll)"]
 String["1.38.1,1.54,0","mingw64-libpango-1_0-0"]
 String["1.38.1,1.54,0","mingw64(libpango-1.0-0.dll)"]
 String["1.38.1,1.54,0","mingw64(libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll)"]
 String["1.38.1,1.54,0","mingw64(libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll)"]
 String["1.38.1,1.54,0","mingw64(libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll)"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, @aviks. So, if I understand correct, as of 0.5.0 there is no WinRPM command that will tell me what packages are installed?